# Babel used with Grunt working differently than when used with Webpack

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a project using Babel for Webpack, transpiling ES6 code into plain Js. This works perfectly well, including the imported classes etc, see below.

**Result:**

```
var _Person = __webpack_require__(2);

var vic = new _Person.person("Fred McIntire", "Web Developer");
vic.EchoProperties();
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
        loader: ['babel'],
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }
    }]
},
```

However while using Babel with Grunt in another project, hence "grunt-babel" plugin, I noticed it transpiles the imports into CommonJs by default and does not include the imported classes.

**Result**

```
var _Person=require("./modules/Person"),
vic=new _Person.person("Fred McIntire","Web Developer");

vic.EchoProperties();
```

**gruntfile.js**

```
    babel: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            presets: ['es2015'],
            plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-amd']
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                'assets/js/transpiled/app.es6.js': 'assets/js/custom/app.js'
            }
        }
    },
```

(I included "plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-amd']" just for testing purposes).

I want the grunt-babel to transpile down to: (and include the imports)

```
var _Person = __webpack_require__(2);
```

not

```
var _Person=require("./modules/Person")
```

Therefore how do i update the gruntfile.js settings for grunt-babel in order to act in the same manner as it does used with Webpack?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You are asking to implement Webpack without using Webpack :P If you want it in a single file, that is what Webpack is for, `grunt-babel` would be mostly for if you wanted to process a bunch of individual files then load each one of them manually.

Comment: You are right... i didn't see that, silly mistake...
However, would it be possible to include the webpack.config.js in the project and somehow initiate and fired as a task in the gruntfile.js?? 
Or is there a plugin that can help transpile the code directly to plain js?

Comment: Just found out it is possible with the "grunt-webpack" plugin... thanks for the pointer